# R - Scraping aspx web error

Tags: asp.net, r, screen-scraping

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=14-12-2016&venue=HV&raceno=1&lang=en"

R1odds <- url %>% read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[2]] %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE)
R1odds
```

I got this error message:

```
Error: input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x3C 0x2F 0x6E 0x6F [6003]
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the following [link](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/117).  This is in a comment since I don't know what the correct output should be to give an answer.  The link suggests you use the `httr` package and something like the following code: `x <- content(GET(url), "raw"); guess_encoding(x)`; this code returns a list of encodings, one of which is `ISO-8859-1`.  So change `read_html()` to `read_html(encoding = "ISO-8859-1")`.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that the rvest return character(0)...
it's aspx.net so I can't scrape the data from it...
any suggestion how to scrape aspx??

Comment: No, not at this point.

Answer (score 0):

For others who might run into something like this in a non-gambling context here's the solution to get round the nulls. You'll have to deal with your gambling data issue on your own:

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)

url <- "http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=14-12-2016&venue=HV&raceno=1&lang=en"

pg <- curl_fetch_memory(url)

pg$content %>%
  readBin(what=character()) %>%
  read_html() -> doc

html_nodes(doc, "table")
## {xml_nodeset (47)}
##  [1] <table width="776" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n  < ...
##  [2] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
##  [3] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
##  [4] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
##  [5] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
##  [6] <table width="776" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n  < ...
##  [7] <table width="776" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n  < ...
##  [8] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
##  [9] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" clas ...
## [10] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [11] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [12] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [13] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [14] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [15] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [16] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [17] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [18] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [19] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## [20] <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n   ...
## ...
```

It's likely the table you need is in there.

For others (since this code works for this site) you may also need to pipe your own data to `iconv()` to deal with other encoding issues.